# Questions about installing php

Tags: php, installation

I'd like to be able to run PHP application on my own windows desktop.

What are my options?
accodring to this [reference](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild), I have to install visual studio 2015 to able to do it. Is it the really necessary?

1. Why do they mention compiling php? it's a scripting language so am I still supposed to pre-compile it before running it?
2. Is Visual Studio the only editor or there are other suggested IDEs?
3. Do I have to run it on IIS, can't I install apache server on my desktop and run the php application on it?

Comment: WAMPServer or XAMPP gets you Apache/MYSQL/PHP all ready to go in 2 clicks

Comment: You could install WAMP and then pick any text editor/IDE you like.

Comment: Cool. I was looking for environment like that. Still I don't understand why the official php wiki refer to Microsoft's visual studio, But I am gonna try XAMPP. Thanks!

Comment: "Why do they mention compiling php?" You're looking at PHP internal resources - like working on the PHP interrupter itself. You can get precompiled PHP interpreters here: http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.1. Q's 2 & 3 are off topic on SO for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you find on the wiki are for building PHP from source, but you don't have to do that to use PHP on Windows.

You can use one of the WAMP/XAMPP packages mentioned in the comments. That's definitely a quick and convenient way to get it working on your system. But if you really just want to put PHP on your Windows machine without using one of those, it really isn't too hard.

Based on your questions, including:

> Why do they mention compiling php?

I think I can safely assume that you *don't* want to compile PHP. Fortunately, you don't have to.

Just go to the [PHP for Windows download page](http://windows.php.net/download#php-7.1) and find the version that will work on your system. The "Which version do I choose?" in the left panel will help you figure out which one you need. These are pretty much ready to use, just extract it where you want it (I usually just do `C:\PHP`).

You will need to have the appropriate C++ redistributable installed before it will work. There are also links to those on the PHP for Windows page that I linked above. If you chose PHP 7 (why not?) it will be the [VC14](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) version.

After you have installed the C++ redistributable and extracted the PHP zip file you downloaded, add the new PHP directory to your Windows path, and you'll be able to use PHP on the command line. You can test that it's working properly with `php -v` (displays the installed version) in a cmd window.

To configure your PHP installation, start with one of the provided ini files, either `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production`. Make a copy of the one you want to use and rename it to `php.ini`.

Of course, this is *only PHP*. If you want to use it to with Apache or some other web server, you'll need to install that separately and configure it to use your PHP installation. It's not difficult after you have some experience with it, but I remember it being pretty frustrating to get it working the first time. The advantage to using XAMPP or similar is that includes Apache and MySQL with one installer. If you're just starting out, that's definitely the easiest way to get going.

---

As far as IDEs, there are various ones that support PHP. There are some free ones that are fine, if that matters to you, but all you *really* need is a good text editor.